# Want to know the position of ESP partition in HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a laptop with 2 SSD connected, named as Disk0 & Disk1 in Disk management. ESP partition and the OS are both present in Disk0. I am using Disk1 as data partition. I am planning to install another OS on the Disk1. Suddenly I had a doubt while looking into the partition structure. ESP is present in Disk0.

Is it possible to create ESP on Disk-1 instead of Disk-0? Or should ESP always be present in Disk0?

Comment: Use the same EFI partition for all OSes installed... this has been asked and answered before, but I don't have the time at the moment to search and post a relevant link. If the second OS is Windows, the default 128MB partition is fine, however if you're installing Linux or BSD, each distro has their own EFI partition size requirements, so verify before installing and enlarge the partition as required _(easiest way is to use [GParted](https://gparted.org/) to move partitions by shrinking the OS partition and moving the freespace next to the EFI partition)_.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the new OS can see and access disk zero, then you should not have to do anything with the EFI system partition except possibly enlarge it (if you're using Linux, chances are it's already more than large enough, but the same may not be true if it's Windows on disk zero). The installer for the new OS should see it and use it by default, and things should Just Work.

However, this setup does have it's drawbacks, namely that if disk zero is removed from the system, this new OS on disk one will not be able to boot (because there will be no EFI system partition any more). You can avoid this by creating a second EFI system partition on disk one, but that brings in it's own issues, namely that the firmware may just ignore it and only look at the ESP on disk 0 (this is technically incorrect behavior per the EFI spec, but I've seen multiple implementations that behave this way).